# API Error when creating new SoftLayer user via python api

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

A script that was previously working started returning the following error when attempting to create a user

> SoftLayerAPIError: SoftLayerAPIError(SoftLayer_Exception_NotReady): Master user must be IBMid authenticated to perform this action

The stack trace indicated the line where the new user password is declared.  Does this mean that the script cannot declare a password (which the API indicates is ignored anyway, though it still requires it), or does that mean that the script has to be authenticated with IBM Id to be able to do user creation at all?

Answer (score 0):

I’m not able to reproduce the error, I’m able to create users no matter if username/apikey of account have IBMid or not (for python client).

I recommend you submit a ticket and provide the code you are using in order to get further assistance with this behavior.

Also you can try the steps described here [switching-to-ibmid](https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2016/10/switching-softlayer-authentication-to-ibmid/), on that page describes how you can switch the account to IBMid. After that, I suggest to review if user/apikey you are using are still the same in order to update python client connection if required.

> About the passwords:
>
> - Neither password nor vpnPassword parameters are required.
> - When a new user is created, an email will be sent to the new user's email address with a link to a url that will allow the new user to create or change their password for the SoftLayer customer portal.
> - If the password parameter is provided and is not null, the user will still receive a portal password email.  It can be used within 24 hours to change their password.
> - If the password parameter is not provided or it is null, the user must set their portal password using the link sent in email within 24 hours.
> - The password parameter is ignored for VPN_ONLY users or for IBMid authenticated users.
> - If the vpnPassword is provided, then the user's vpnPassword will be set to the provided password.  When creating a vpn only user, the vpnPassword MUST be supplied.

You can also review the following pages.

https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2016/10/switching-softlayer-authentication-to-ibmid/ 
https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/troubleshoot/ts_accessing.html#accessing

Regards,